# Create custom fields in user profile section for uploading the resume of a user

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add an option on the edit profile page to upload the user's resume. I have to try adding some function but not getting results.

Comment: Syntax improving

Comment: Reformatting the question for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

with the plugin ACF (advancedcustomfields.com)
You can create customs fields in user profile.

1. ACF > Group Field
2. Create resume (type file)
3. Affect Form user (add / edit)

[image: ACF Plugin]

In your template, use `get_field('resume', USER_ID);` for show file
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/

If no template, use the shortcode `[acf field="resume"]`
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/

Happy New Year and best wishes :D

Comment: I am not using any custom template

Comment: Use the shortcode [acf field="resume"]
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/